# Vlookup and counting unique values

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, vlookup

So in Column A is "PS Department" and in Column B is "Cost Center"

Several PS Departments have multiple Cost Centers and I want to count the number of unique Cost Centers that map to each PS Department.

So far, I've been stuck at: =COUNTIF(B:B,VLOOKUP(A2,A:B,2,FALSE))

This obviously doesn't give me the number of unique values, but rather the number of entries that meet this criteria.

Hope this makes sense and I can provide any additional information if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$15=A2,1/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$15,$B$2:$B$15,$A$2:$A$15,A2)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mod.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]